# Color extraction, quantification and analysis from image in R

Tags: r, image, colors, analysis, quantization

I would like to `quantifying colors in an image`. 
I work on the iridescence of nacre (mother of pearl), and I want to quantifying three colors (**red, yellow and green**) on this shell (for example on the right picture on the link above).

[Iridescence of nacre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIynZ.jpg)

So, I had test some packages (`imager`,  `ImageMagick`, `EBImage`...), but I don't really find something that help me.

Well, **I would like to make color quantification** on `R`, with circles. The area of ​​the primitive in pixel may be expressed as that of a circle of equivalent surface area. The primitive is a contiguous area of neighboring pixels of similar color. The center of the circle can be the anchor pixel. 
So, there is the equation which I think it's ok to do this:

> DeltaI = square root[(Ranchor - Ri)² - (Ganchor - Gi)² - (Banchor -
>   Bi)²]

Where R,G and B are color components of a pixel, ranging from 0 to 255, anchor is the anchor pixel and i is any pixel around the anchor pixel which are the same equivalent color.

There is a image link to the expectation results (from [Alçiçek & Balaban 2012](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/41113722/tiger_prawn.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1486502777&Signature=ZcX1eV8nqS1%2BYRSgvJZyAURvCwo%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DVisual_Attributes_of_Hot_Smoked_King_Sal.pdf)):

[Shrimp resulting equivalent circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMgXt.png)

So there is my (bootable worked) code, but I have really no idea how to continue.. May be try to create a package ?

```
library(png)
nacre <-  readPNG("test.png")
nacre

dim(nacre)

# show the full RGB image
grid.raster(nacre)

# show the 3 channels in separate images
nacre.R = nacre
nacre.G = nacre
nacre.B = nacre

# zero out the non-contributing channels for each image copy
nacre.R[,,2:3] = 0
nacre.G[,,1]=0
nacre.G[,,3]=0
nacre.B[,,1:2]=0

# build the image grid
img1 = rasterGrob(nacre.R)
img2 = rasterGrob(nacre.G)
img3 = rasterGrob(nacre.B)
grid.arrange(img1, img2, img3, nrow=1)
# Now let’s segment this image. First, we need to reshape the array into a data frame with one row for each pixel and three columns for the RGB channels:


# reshape image into a data frame
df = data.frame(
red = matrix(nacre[,,1], ncol=1),
green = matrix(nacre[,,2], ncol=1),
blue = matrix(nacre[,,3], ncol=1)
  )


### compute the k-means clustering
K = kmeans(df,4)
df$label = K$cluster

### Replace the color of each pixel in the image with the mean 
### R,G, and B values of the cluster in which the pixel resides:

# get the coloring
colors = data.frame(
  label = 1:nrow(K$centers), 
  R = K$centers[,"red"],
  G = K$centers[,"green"],
  B = K$centers[,"blue"]
)

# merge color codes on to df
df$order = 1:nrow(df)
df = merge(df, colors)
df = df[order(df$order),]
df$order = NULL

# get mean color channel values for each row of the df.
R = matrix(df$R, nrow=dim(nacre)[1])
G = matrix(df$G, nrow=dim(nacre)[1])
B = matrix(df$B, nrow=dim(nacre)[1])

# reconstitute the segmented image in the same shape as the input image
nacre.segmented = array(dim=dim(nacre))
nacre.segmented[,,1] = R
nacre.segmented[,,2] = G
nacre.segmented[,,3] = B

# View the result
grid.raster(nacre.segmented)
```

Someone have a track or any idea ?
Thanks for any help..

Comment: Can you provide the exact citation /article for the  "Shrimp resulting equivalent circles" ? I looked into the " Alçiçek & Balaban 2012" paper and that picture is not there!

Comment: @Daniel, there is the good link to the article (unfortunately, I can't post an url link on edit before I've 2 post and 10 reputation.. And I understand that's why the image can't be see by others..)
http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/41113722/tiger_prawn.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1486502777&Signature=ZcX1eV8nqS1%2BYRSgvJZyAURvCwo%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DVisual_Attributes_of_Hot_Smoked_King_Sal.pdf

Comment: OK, Thanks I updated your reference!

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've find a other way to answer my question:

- I upload my image with `load.image`from `imager` package.
- I extract the RGB channels with this code:

  ```
  # Assign RGB channels to data frame
  nacreRGB <- data.frame(
  x = rep(1:nacreDm[2], each = nacreDm[1]),
  y = rep(nacreDm[1]:1, nacreDm[2]),
  R = as.vector(nacre[,,1]),
  G = as.vector(nacre[,,2]),
  B = as.vector(nacre[,,3])
  )
  # head(nacreRGB)

  # Assign RGB channels to data frame without pixel coordinates
  nacreRGB2 <- data.frame(
  R = as.vector(nacre[,,1]),
  G = as.vector(nacre[,,2]),
  B = as.vector(nacre[,,3])
  ```
- After I convert this into HEX code with `rgbSVG2rgbCSS` fonction.
- I put this into a matrix which I call `RGB0` to create histogramms and show the different colors with the pixels frequencies.
- After I perform a PCA to show the distribution of these colors:

  ```
  require("ggplot2")
  RGB0 <- as.data.frame(RGB0)

  # perform PCA on the nacre data and add the uv coordinates to the 
  dataframe
  PCA = prcomp(RGB0[,c("R","G","B")], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
  RGB0$u = PCA$x[,1]
  RGB0$v = PCA$x[,2]
  ```
- I show this PCA with `ggplot2`.
- After this I translate the RGB code into HSV code with `rgb2hsv` and I can have a value for the hue, for saturation (hue to white) and value (hue to dark), so I can obtain qualities and quantities datas about colors.

Edit : All codes are now publishing into CRAN in ImaginR package : 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ImaginR/ImaginR.pdf

Or on GitHub :
https://github.com/PLStenger/ImaginR

This version not really quantifying the color, but it will appears soon in the next version.

Comment: Could you please share GitHub link? THX